# how to get specifically child's row and column in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am absolutely bigenner in android programming. I have done so far like this..

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scorecard_fragment, container,
            false);

    gridLayout = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.GridLayout1);

    /*** Default first row */

    gridLayout.setColumnCount(col);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(row);

    if (col == 1) {
        defaultColumn();
    }

    else {

        extendedColumn("");

    }
    return view;
}

public void defaultColumn() {
    // Log.d(TAG, "Default col");

    int i;
    int k = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        if (i == 0)

        {

            ImageView oImageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
            oImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_player);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new   
  GridLayout.LayoutParams();

            param.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

            gridLayout.addView(oImageView);

        } else if (i < 19) {

            TextView oTextView = new TextView(getActivity());

            oTextView.append("" + (k++) + "\n");
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            param.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
            oTextView.setLayoutParams(param);
            gridLayout.addView(oTextView);

        } else {

            TextView oTextView = new TextView(getActivity());

            oTextView.append("\n");
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            param.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
            oTextView.setLayoutParams(param);
            gridLayout.addView(oTextView);

        }

    }
    col++;

}

public void extendedColumn(String str) {

    Log.d("", "value c1" + col);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        if (i == 0)

        {

            TextView oTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
            oTextView.setText(str);
            gridLayout.addView(oTextView);
            // oTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
            oTextView.setTextSize(14);

        }

        else if (i < 19) {

            Log.d("Implement spinner", "sdfsdfsdf");

            final Spinner s1 = new Spinner(getActivity());

            final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
                    .createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.score_array,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    updateResult();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

            gridLayout.addView(s1);

        }

        else {
            TextView oTextView = new TextView(getActivity());

            oTextView.append("\n");
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
            param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            param.setMargins(15, 15, 15, 15);
            oTextView.setLayoutParams(param);
            gridLayout.addView(oTextView);

        }
    }
    col++;

}

public void updateResult() {

    int j = gridLayout.getColumnCount();

    Log.d(" Column count", "" + j);

    int k = gridLayout.getRowCount();

    Log.d(" Row count", "" + k);

}
```

As you can see I am trying get the value from spinner and its current row and column value. I can do that using gridLayout.getColumnCount() and gridLayout.getRowCount(). But that gives me always the total column and row depend on how many user I have. But I want to get the **specific row and column** no matter how many user I have so that I can calculate my result by knowing which **row and column** has been selected by which user..Helps or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`so that I can calculate my result by knowing which value has been selected`

To only know the selected value, just implement the `onItemClick()` method, and inside you will have `position` of selected value, the `view`, the `parent` ViewGroup, etc ...